# Converting Column into Negative Numbers based on string in cell to the left of the Number Column

Tags: vba, excel

So within my macro I'm trying to change all the numbers in Column C into negative numbers if Column A has the word "remit", but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong with my code. I'm getting a "Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed":

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet    
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False

With ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1LR)
   .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*Remit*"
 Set rngFiltered = Range("C1:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 rngFiltered.Value = rng.Filtered.Value * -1
End With
```

And why I try the range this way I get 'Object required':

```
With ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1LR)
   .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*Remit*"
 Set rngFiltered = Range("C1:C" & ws1LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 rngFiltered.Value = rng.Filtered.Value * -1
End With
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to change all of `C` based on `"remit"` showing up at least once (with no other dependency) then I would use [`Range(..).Find(..)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) instead of `AutoFilter` because it's much more straightforward to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you require, make sure you change the decalred sheet name to match your sheet name.

It uses Range Find as suggested by Marcucciboy2.

For a sheet with lots of rows of data, it may take sometime to complete.

```
Sub NegativeRemitNumbers()

Dim SearchName As Variant
Dim NumberChange As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to match your sheet name

For Each SearchName In ws.Range("A:A") ' This is the column we will search 

   If SearchName.Value = "remit" Then ' if the serach vale = Remit then turn the number negative

       NumberChange = ws.Cells(SearchName.Row, 3).Value ' get the number value in colunm C
       NumberChange = NumberChange - NumberChange - NumberChange ' Take away the value from itself twice to get a negative value (there maybe better ways to do this but this was quick to write)
       ws.Cells(SearchName.Row, 3).Value = NumberChange ' replace the positive number with the negative positive number

   End If

Next 

End Sub
```

Using this code, if you were to run it twice then it will revert the negative numbers back to positive, you will need to add an if statement check that the number is not negative before processing that cell value.

Comment: Are you scanning all 1048576 cells? Shouldn't you calculate the last cell in the column?

Comment: This code is not effeciant and can be adpted for better performance, including finding the last cell, data validation, disabling screen updates and so on, but that wont help anyone who is looking for an answer to the original question. This was very vaguely pointed out in my answer.